# Crear múltiples rutas con google maps y flutter

Tags: flutter

¿Cómo puedo crear un mapa con múltiples direcciones?
La idea es tener una ruta de inicio, varios puntos intermedios y ruta final.
He visto mucho código pero nada que se acerque.

Tengo los datos de *latlng* de una base de datos MySQL.

```dart
Future<void> papa() async {
    markers.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < order.travels!.length; i++) {
      print("For Loop");
      final marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(order.travels![i].idTravel!),
        position: LatLng(order.travels![i].lat!, order.travels![i].lng!),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: order.travels![i].idTravel!,
          snippet: order.travels![i].address!,
        ),
      );
      print("${order.travels![i].lat!}, ${order.travels![i].lng!}");
      print('soy la travel: ${order.travels![i].idTravel}');
      markers[order.travels![i].idTravel!] = marker;

    }
  }
```

El log:

```
I/flutter (11048): For Loop
I/flutter (11048): -33.538066655809, -33.538066655809
I/flutter (11048): soy la travel: 1
I/flutter (11048): dere: 1
I/flutter (11048): For Loop
I/flutter (11048): -33.53965704235282, -70.78540194779634
I/flutter (11048): soy la travel: 2
I/flutter (11048): dere: 2
I/flutter (11048): For Loop
I/flutter (11048): -33.53609449114154, -70.77957551926374
I/flutter (11048): soy la travel: 3
I/flutter (11048): dere: 3
I/flutter (11048): la cantidad: 3
```

[image: imagen con 2 markets]

Comment: Hola Cachi, bienvenido, la idea detrás del funcionamiento de este sitio, es ayudar a los programadores a resolver los problemas que se encuentran durante la creación de aplicaciones, muéstranos que has realizado, que problemas tienes, y trabajaremos juntos para solventarlos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: hola, el problema que tengo es el ciclo for, me muestra bien el length , pero al crear los markers en el mapa, me resta 1, si length es = 3, me crea solo 2 markers.

Comment: trato de subir el codigo pero no me deja, soy nuevo aca:

Comment: void addmarket() async{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < order.travels!.length ; i++){
      deliveryMarker = await createMarkerFromAssets('assets/img/taxi_icon.png');
      markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(i.toString()),
        position: LatLng(double.parse(order.travels![i].lat.toString()), double.parse(order.travels![i].lng.toString())),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Ruta ${[i]}',
          snippet: '5 Star Rating',
        ),
        icon: deliveryMarker!,

      ));


    }

  }

Comment: No añadas código en los comentarios. Edita la pregunta y añádelo ahí.

Comment: Amigo, encontré el error , tenia en una dirección lat y lng el mismo valor, leyendo tus comentarios en otras preguntas, me puse a detallar el código. gracias.

Comment: Alguien que me oriente a crear una ruta con varias direcciones tomadas de una DB